# How to collect clever problem-solving instances in movies

Tags: support

I've just watched the Bourne series again in preparation for Jason Bourne, and greatly enjoyed some of the clever escapes that the protagonist employed. For example,

- to start a fire with a delay, put a magazine or newspaper in the toaster
- to escape surveillance, time your walk with that of a protest/march, and blend in

How should a question be phrased so as to be on topic for the site?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MacGyvering and the related tropes and indexes

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure there is a way to phrase the question you want to be on-topic, and still get you the answer you want. It sounds like what you want is an open-ended list of things, and those are almost always going to be out of scope on any SE site.

I suspect some of the things you want could be found on the TV Tropes site, maybe start with the tropes list for the Bourne series and go from there?

---

To be clear: I'm absolutely not saying we aren't willing to help you figure out what questions are on-topic, or how to ask one that is likely to get an answer. But that question is probably not going to be exactly the same one you had in mind when you came here. The fact that you're asking for help phrasing your question means you recognize that the core of it is off-topic; the only way to fix that is to change the question.

That new question may well be interesting and useful in its own right; if that's true then you're strongly encouraged to ask it. Just be aware -- it's probably not going to get the answers you were originally looking for.

Comment: Would Quora be a better place to ask that question then? I've searched there and found that a similar question for business, [What's the shrewdest, smartest maneuver you've ever seen in business?](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-shrewdest-smartest-maneuver-youve-ever-seen-in-business), has yielded amazingly interesting content.

Comment: Possibly. Quora has a more more open-ended format than SE; their posts range from Q&A, to discussions, to wholesale articles.